# javascript style.top / left dont work in a div

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to move a div modifying this.elemento.style.top and this.elemento.style.left.

As you can see , first of all get the value of style.top and style.left and then try to modifying the value of sttyle.top /left by hand on the console :

```
>>> this.elemento.style.top 
"48px"
>>> this.elemento.style.left
"18px"
>>> this.elemento.style.top = "500px";
"500px"
>>> this.elemento.style.left = "500px";
"500px"
```

https://gyazo.com/090bb475a3affc117ea5c729a04b8cf3

When I use this.elemento it is just a div in hmtl. This is the example :  https://gyazo.com/66503fe34e63deba778fc2da70da8a59

Comment: What is the value of `style.position`?

Comment: >>>this.elemento.style.position is empty

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, position should be set to something else then "static" which is it's default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to give the div an absolute position. To do this you need to give its parent container position relative. 
In your CSS add this.

```
#parent{
  position: relative;
}
#child{
  position: absolute;
}
```

If you prefer to do it in JS then add this to your JS file:

```
parent.elemento.style.position = relative; 
this.elemento.style.position = absolute;
```